# Index Match and Sum across multiple tables

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum the number of FTE at each grade with a particular capability... I have 10 tables where:

Column A = Offering / Capability List (this is different for each table)
Row A = Grades (this is the same for every table)

The tables are all the same size. (as per screenshot 1)

I know how to Index Match to find the answer for a single table, but how could I do this across 10... Of course, I could repeat the formula manually and shift the cell references for each table but I am hoping there is a more efficient way...

Examples here of the input (sheet with 10 tables) and output (where i am putting the formula) sheets here...

http://postimg.org/gallery/zewansp0/

[image]

[image]

My current formula in the output sheet is: `=INDEX('Offering to FTE'!C5:L25,MATCH(B4,'Offering to FTE'!B5:B25,0),MATCH(C3,'Offering to FTE'!C4:L4,0))+INDEX('Offering to FTE'!C31:L51,MATCH(B4,'Offering to FTE'!B31:B51,0),MATCH(C3,'Offering to FTE'!C4:L4,0))+INDEX('Offering to FTE'!C57:L77,MATCH(B4,'Offering to FTE'!B57:B77,0),MATCH(C3,'Offering to FTE'!C4:L4,0))`

This does what I need but only for three tables.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thankyou

Comment: is the order of `Partner,Director,..` the same on all tables and do they always line up in the same column?

Comment: Yup! Always the same column in the input tables!

Comment: Then  simple SUMIF() should work. something like `=SUMIF('Offering to FTE'!$B:$B,$B4,'Offering to FTE'!D:D)` where D:D is the column in which Partner is found.  Then drag over and down.

Comment: Thankyou v v much! Not sure why I was over complicating it.